# Solution of the differential equation : $x\cdot y' \cdot \ln{y \over x} = x+y\cdot \ln{y \over x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Which function is the solution of the differential equation
>   $\displaystyle x\cdot y' \cdot \ln{y \over x} = x+y\cdot \ln{y \over x}$
>   1) $\displaystyle {y \over x}\ln\left|{y \over x}\right| - \frac{y^2}{2x^2} = \ln|x| + c$
>   2) $\displaystyle {y \over x}\ln\left|{y \over x}\right| + \frac{y^2}{2x^2} = \ln|x| + c$
>   3) $\displaystyle {y \over x}\ln\left|{y \over x}\right| - \frac{y^2}{x^2} = \ln|x| + c$
>   4) $\displaystyle {y \over x}\ln\left|{y \over x}\right| - \frac{y^2}{2x} = \ln|x| + c$

My steps so far are:
$y=vx$, $y'=v'x+v$, so the equation becomes
$x\left(v'x+v\right)\ln v = x+vx\ln v$
$v'x^2\ln v = x$, let $x\ne 0$
$\ln v dv = \frac{1}{x} dx$
$v(\ln v -1) = \ln x+ C$, it's none of the above.

> Where did I go wrong?

[Here](http://cs626120.vk.me/v626120848/6e5/mfHPwLCDurM.jpg) is the image of the task.

Comment: To me, you did it well and none of the possible answers is correct

Comment: Now I'm sure. Thank you.